# Why does my Solve output contain this symbol?

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting, warning-messages, polynomials

I have a pair of coupled polynomial equations that I need to solve, so I tried using Mathematica's solve tool. This is the code that I wrote:

```
Solve[4*x^3 *(a^2 - y^2) + 6*x^2 * (a - y)^2  + 6*x^2 == 0 && 
x^3*(2*(a - y)^2 + x*(a^2 - y^2 )) + x^6 == 0, {x, y}, Reals,]
```

But I'm getting the following message and output:
[image]

I think the message is trying to tell me that I have given more variables than equations, but I listed only x and y as my variables, and have provided only two equations. On the other hand, I have no idea how to interpret this "stand-in" symbol(the #) that keeps popping up in my output, which is not even close to what it should be(although I guess fixing the errors will rectify this).

Can someone please explain these peculiarities and how to deal with them?

Comment: Look at the documentation of [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) (the symbol that is wrapped around the slots (the `#1`)) - that should answer your question

Comment: Use Reduce instead of Solve and you will obtain a closed-form expression in version 11.3.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is meant by "stand-in symbol". The message is just a warning that some solution(s) only solve for one variable. The reason is that is `x=0` then both equations vanish independent of `y`.

To remove this situation one can "quotient out" that solution (I use the term informally, but it does correspond to an ideal quotient in commutative algebra). The method is quite simple: just add a new variable and equation forcing `x` not to vanish. I added `x*xr==1` where `xr` is meant to denote "reciprocal of `x`". The version below will give a solution set sans warning message.

```
Solve[{4*x^3*(a^2 - y^2) + 6*x^2*(a - y)^2 + 6*x^2 == 0, 
  x^3*(2*(a - y)^2 + x*(a^2 - y^2)) + x^6 == 0, x*xr == 1}, {xr, x, 
  y}, Reals]
```

You might consider not using the domain specification `Reals` because it complicates the solution set with conditions on the parameter `a` (but if you really require those conditions then it's of course fine to retain the domain specification).

Comment: I meant the `#` symbol followed by `1`; it popped up one time in place of the variable when I typed f' instead of f'[x], so I just assumed it is a stand-in symbol for a variable. I just tried your code, and there is no error. However, there are still lots of these "slot" symbols, but I need an expression that gives me a real `x` and `y`(these are physical quantities) in terms of `a`. And I still don't understand what to make of these "slots".

Comment: Ah. The responses by @JohnDoty and @HenrikSchumacher explain that. In short, they are needed to express `Root` objects that encode solutions in a manner that generalizes radicals. (Okay, maybe that wasn't so short...)

Answer (score 1):

```
soln = Solve[{4*x^3*(a^2 - y^2) + 6*x^2*(a - y)^2 + 6*x^2 == 0, 
x^3*(2*(a - y)^2 + x*(a^2 - y^2)) + x^6 == 0, x*xr == 1}, {xr, x, 
y}, Reals];
soln /. a -> 1.5
```

Yielding:

```
{{xr -> Undefined, x -> Undefined, y -> Undefined}, 
{xr -> Undefined, x -> Undefined, y -> Undefined}, 
{xr -> 0.896557, x -> 1.11538, y -> 1.97412}, 
{xr -> Undefined, x -> Undefined, y -> Undefined}, 
{xr -> 1.38467, x -> 0.722195, y -> 2.99889}, 
{xr -> Undefined, x -> Undefined, y -> Undefined}, 
{xr -> Undefined, x -> Undefined, y -> Undefined}, 
{xr -> Undefined, x -> Undefined, y -> Undefined}, 
{xr -> Undefined, x -> Undefined, y -> Undefined}, 
{xr -> Undefined, x -> Undefined, y -> Undefined}}
```

To get a numeric answer, you must provide a value for `a`. The `Undefined` values correspond to solutions that are complex.

`Root` objects on polynomial functions are a generalization of radicals, especially useful in cases, as here, where no representation of the expression in terms of radicals exists. Treat them the way you'd treat `Sqrt[a]`.

If you use the exact `3/2` rather than the approximate `1.5` above, you get much longer expressions involving `Root` objects with exact constant coefficients. These represent exact algebraic numbers, just like `Sqrt[3/2]` does.